# Access denied error while adding certificate credential to Azure AD Application

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I am adding a certificate credential to a registered application on an Azure AD tenant by executing following commands:

```
connect-msolservice
$cer = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate
$cer.Import("<Cert path>")
$binCert = $cer.GetRawCertData()
$credValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($binCert);
New-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId "<AppID>" -Type asymmetric -Value $credValue -Usage verify
```

These commands are taken from [this sample](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/Daemon-CertificateCredential-DotNet) . I am signing with the account of a user on the directory. However, the last command is throwing an exception of '**Access Denied. You do not have permissions to call this 
cmdlet**'. According to the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn194106.aspx), it is not mentioned if this command execution requires to be from an administrator account. If i change the user role to be service/global administrator on the Azure AD, the command succeeds. Interestingly, I am able to execute the command on a different Azure AD, where the account is just an user. Is there anything else in play here? Can a user account be given permission to execute this cmdlet?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have reached your subscription limit or your subscription has expired. 
you need to follow up with ms team. This is not a code issue.